# case_when over multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a DF with 4 coulmns and I'm trying to use case_when:

```
myDF %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = c(Coder_1, Coder_2, Coder_3),
                ~case_when(coderAvg == "1" ~ 1)))
```

Whenever there is the value `1` under `coderAvg` column,

it sets the value "1" under all the columns: `Coder_1`, `Coder_2`, `Coder_3`
and it works fine.

The problem is that whenever `coderAvg` has different value,
it sets these columns (`Coder_1`, `Coder_2`, `Coder_3`) into NA.

I've tried to use

```
~case_when(coderAvg == "1" ~ 1,
               TRUE ~ ???)))
```

what what should I write insted of the ??? so that values remain the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need this:
updated

```
myDF %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = c(Coder_1, Coder_2, Coder_3),
                ~ifelse(coderAvg == "1",1, .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myDF %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = c(Coder_1, Coder_2, Coder_3),
                ~case_when(coderAvg == "1" ~ 1,TRUE~.x)))
```